# Were Accounts Purged?

Tags: support, bug

I participated early on in the beta, but found that when I logged in after the official launch I didn't have any reputation or history. Are/were accounts inactive for a period of time purged?

Comment: same user name? SE doesn't typically purge users. Is it possible you were unregistered and have lost your cookie?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, same username. I even went through the effort of trying each combination of account login I could think of, but no dice... they all asked to confirm that I wanted to create a new account.

I doubt I posted anonymously, unless there was no other way to do so. But it's definitely possible (I definitely wouldn't have that cookie still in my cache).

Comment: I can confirm that in the database there is no "Mad Brew" before yesterday. I will have to check re purging... I wouldn't have thought so, but I'm not usually involved in new site creation etc. Also... you have 2 accounts now... that is abnormal.

Comment: So that I know where to look, did you post anything or add any comments?

Comment: I can definitely remember answering/commenting and voting things up. The only other name/pseudonym I could imagine is "Mad Brew" with or without spaces, possibly appending "Labs" to that (my blog's name) or using "Michael Brewer." 

It's not a big deal, I was just wondering at not having my account persist. I appreciate the investigation though, thanks.

Comment: @MarcGravell Not sure if you saw the comment response here, so... ping. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I have to say as I'm looking around at old Q&A's I'm seeing a lot more greyed out accounts than I'm used to. We used to just have a couple.  Now, like [How do you help players not focus on the rules?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6212/how-do-you-help-players-not-focus-on-the-rules) - there's two expired user accounts there.  Even as a mod I can't see anything about them.  But it does seem like a sharp noticeable increase. We used to have just a handful and we knew them all (malcontents who demanded to be deleted).

Comment: Heheh, I am sure I was never a malcontent, my limited attention spanned was drawn elsewhere. Thanks for poking around.